# How to constrain db elements in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have four tables in my db `Movie`, `Showing`, `Ticket` and `Purchase`. A Movie has many `Showing`s, a `Showing` has many `Ticket`s and a `Purchase` has many `Ticket`s.

I'd like to constrain it so that all the `Ticket`s in the `Purchase` can only be for exactly one `Movie`. I'm new to Rails and wondered if there was a way to do this in the Model. (`validate` or something similar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Purchase
  validate :validate_same_movie

  private

  def validate_same_movie
    movie_ids = tickets.map do |ticket|
      ticket.showing.movie.id
    end.uniq

    errors[:base] << "Can't have more than one movie in a purchase." if movie_ids.length > 1
  end
end
```

Something along these lines.

But I would also urge you to think about exactly why you're introducing this additional complexity into your system.  In my experience, I typically buy movie tickets for the same movie at once and I don't recall when I've bought tickets for different movies in a single purchase.  But just because I haven't done it doesn't mean nobody does.  You're adding complexity and you're reducing functionality of your site.  I'm not saying you don't have a valid reason, because I don't know what your app is.. but just a suggestion that you might think about if you really need this.

Comment: Thank you. It's not really movies and tickets, but the domain-specific terminology would detract.

Comment: Oh, well in that case ignore my second paragraph. :)  Hope the validate code helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```
class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :movie
  has_many :tickets
end

class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :purchase
end

class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :purchases
end
```

Comment: I don't wish to change the design to add a relationship between `Movie` and `Purchase`, I just want to constrain that `Purchase` must include `Ticket`s for only one `Movie`.